# How to draw things only in a certain area?

Tags: java, canvas, draw, area

I'm making a tower defense game and I will have certain markers that have the possibility of being drawn outside the game grid depending on where they are placed. I've been drawing everything on one canvas that is my game class and I was wondering if there was a way I could draw certain things only in a set area (in this case my game grid).

To explain it better, if a circle was to be drawn on the edge of the game grid, id like the overhang to be cut off.

What my gui looks like:

[image: Maze]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way might be to adjust the clipping of the `Graphics` context.  I personally, don't like messing with the clip as it can seriously screw up on you if you're not careful.

Take a look at [Clipping the Drawing Region](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/clipping.html) for more details

**Clipping example**

[image: Clipping]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestClip {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestClip();
    }

    public TestClip() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;

        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("Lurk.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
            g2d.setClip(101, 101, 199, 199);
            g2d.drawImage(img, 300 - (img.getWidth() / 2), (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

Another way might be to generate a transparent `BufferedImage` to act as a layer, which you can ensure is the correct size you want to restrict the painting to, draw those additional elements onto it and the draw the resulting `BufferedImage` over the top of the map

**Layer example**

[image: Layer]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestClip {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestClip();
    }

    public TestClip() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;
        private BufferedImage layer;

        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("Lurk.png"));
                layer = new BufferedImage(199, 199, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                Graphics2D g2d = layer.createGraphics();
                g2d.drawImage(img, 
                        layer.getWidth() - (img.getWidth() / 2), 
                        (layer.getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2, 
                        this);
                g2d.dispose();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
            g2d.drawImage(layer, 101, 101, this);
//            g2d.setClip(101, 101, 199, 199);
//            g2d.drawImage(img, 300 - (img.getWidth() / 2), (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I never knew about setClip(). Right now I have it setup in my foreground rendering so it wont interfere with any important things going on in the rest of the game. If something goes wrong i'll look into the layer method. Thanks again!